# Why doesn't Fancybox window popup?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have installed and configured Fancybox 2 on this page: http://southernlivingplants.com/carmen_johnston/

The first video placeholder has a YouTube video linked to it. It is supposed to pop up in a Fancybox window, but it just goes directly to the YouTube page.

I have checked it in FireBug and don't get any errors. Everything appears to be loading correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
    media : {}
    }
   });
  });   
</script>
```

Any clues what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video can be shown in iframe type. To use this we you can use two below approaches :

1) Either add a class "iframe" in the anchor tag along with "fancybox-media". Code will be same for js for example:

```
<a href="youtube url" class="fancybox-media iframe"><img /></a>
```

2) Or define type in script code of fancybox, i.e.

```
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    type : 'iframe',
    // existing stuff   
});
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Hi Kundan, This is close. The window pops up, but the video does not display. Please review again. Thanks!

Comment: @fmz, I guess the video url is wrong. Try this instead **http://www.youtube.com/embed/aAhPaiajwDY**

Comment: Yes, that makes the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest you take a look at following example.

http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-download/responsive-youtube-videos/fancybox-youtube.html

Just inspect the html code and js snippet, and you pretty much can apply that to your website.

Comment: Their site works, but when I copied the code over it still goes directly to YouTube. There must be something interfering.